# Silex sessions not saving data?

Tags: php, silex

After finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734549/sessions-do-not-work-in-silex-app) I got my Silex sessions to at least get an ID assigned, but I'm not seeing the session data get saved across different page views:

```
require(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'); // Composer autoload

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app['db'] = $app->share(function() { // Database connector as a service
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myawesome_db', 'user', 'paswd');
});

$app['session.db_options'] = array(
    'db_table'      => 'php_sessions',
    'db_id_col'     => 'session_id',
    'db_data_col'   => 'session_value',
    'db_time_col'   => 'session_time',
);

$app['session.storage.pdohandler'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler(
        $app['db'],
        $app['session.db_options'],
        $app['session.storage.options']
    );
});
$app['session.storage'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage(
        $app['session.storage.options'],
        $app['session.storage.pdohandler']
    );
});
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider()); // Start session management
$app['session']->start();

$app->get('/session-set', function() use ($app) {
    $app['session']->set('foobar', 'test');
    $app['session']->save();
    $out = "User session is: ".$app['session']->getId()."<br />\n";
    $out .= "Session variable is: ".var_export($app['session']->get('foobar'), true)."<br />\n";
    return $out;
});
$app->get('/session-get', function() use ($app) {
    $out = "User session is: ".$app['session']->getId()."<br />\n";
    $out .= "Session variable is: ".var_export($app['session']->get('foobar'), true)."<br />\n";
    return $out;
});

$app->run(); // Off into the sunset
```

The `/session-set` page shows a value for the `foobar` session variable, but the `/session-get` page does not. Anyone able to help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution turned out to be that the PDO database connection was not set up properly (one of the column names was wrong). However, by default, the PDO MySQL connection doesn't throw Exceptions when it errors out, it just sets the `ErrorInfo()` detail. Once I turned on Exception throwing for my PDO connection, I found the error and fixed it. I also submitted a patch to Symfony to ensure that the session PDO object has Exception-throwing enabled, to avoid others hitting this problem.